# Constructing equilateral triangle from three equilateral triangles.

Tags: geometry, centroid

I have heard about this problem some time ago and don't remember all the details.Therefore problem's conditions may have some mistakes.
Problem:

> We have three arbitrary (size of edges, location and orientation in space are random) equilateral triangles ABC, DEF and GHI. If we draw lines from corresponding
>   corners we create three new triangles. After defining centroids of new triangles and connecting them, we always get another equilateral triangle. Question is to proof this.

[image]

I tried drawing and it seemed quite true. Then I try to calculate but It take too much time. After I decided, to get solution using python and sympy. Formulas that I get from them didn't match. But I think there is mistake in program.There is link to [notebook code](https://mega.nz/#!zaJmHILY!LUPBjWVErG7APN9XVrbRVK6HBOa1n-2YzwBAA-VZkhc) .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess, I can help with solution when initial triangles are simultaneously labeled clockwise or counterclockwise.
Consider everything happens in a complex plane, thus every point corresponds to some complex number $z = x + yi$.

Let's consider how an equilateral triangle can be defined within this setup.
I propose the following.
Let a complex number $z$ define its centroid.
Now I define one of its vertices as $z + v$, where $v$ is some other complex number.
This information is enough to fully recover triangle's position and rotation, thus two other vertices may be written in terms of $z$ and $v$ as $z + v e^{2\pi i/3}$ and $z + v e^{-2\pi i/3}$ (I omit the proof as it seems quite obvious).

Now the original problem.
I can write coordinates of vertices in terms of parameters $z_1$, $z_2$, $z_3$, $v_1$, $v_2$, $v_3$ as follows (rows of the table describe the original triangles, while reading through columns we see points in a rearranged order, thus "new triangles" in problem statement)
$$
\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
  \text{Triangle/Triangle} & \triangle ADG & \triangle BEH & \triangle CFI \\ 
\hline
   \triangle ABC & z_1 + v_1 & z_1 + e^{2\pi i/3} v_1 & z_1 + e^{-2\pi i/3} v_1 \\
\hline
   \triangle DEF & z_2 + v_2 & z_2 + e^{2\pi i/3} v_2 & z_2 + e^{-2\pi i/3} v_2 \\
\hline
   \triangle GHI & z_3 + v_3 & z_3 + e^{2\pi i/3} v_3 & z_3 + e^{-2\pi i/3} v_3 \\
\hline
\end{array}
$$

Now we can write centroids for new triangles
$$
\begin{align}
O &= \frac{z_1 + z_2 + z_3 + v_1 + v_2 + v_3}{3}\\
L &= \frac{z_1 + z_2 + z_3 + e^{2\pi i/3}v_1 + e^{2\pi i/3}v_2 + e^{2\pi i/3}v_3}{3}\\
P &= \frac{z_1 + z_2 + z_3 + e^{-2\pi i/3}v_1 + e^{-2\pi i/3}v_2 + e^{-2\pi i/3}v_3}{3}\\
\end{align}
$$
Obviously, they are vertices of an equilateral triangle.
Why?
Lets define
$$
\begin{align}
Z &= \frac{z_1 + z_2 + z_3}{3}\\
V &= \frac{v_1 + v_2 + v_3}{3}
\end{align}
$$
Than we can write
$$
\begin{align}
O &= Z + V\\
L &= Z + e^{2\pi i/3}V\\
P &= Z + e^{-2\pi i/3}V\\
\end{align}
$$
that corresponds to the way, we used to define equilateral triangles.

Comment: +1. In fact, there's nothing special about equilateral triangles here; all that matters is that the original triangles are *similar* (and simultaneously clockwise or counter-clockwise), in which case the final triangle will be similar to them. Your argument works when the $z_i$ are *circumcenters* and $\pm 2\pi/3$ are replaced by appropriately-signed central angles.

Comment: @Blue , you're right. Probably, we can do even a step more and consider some polygons instead of triangles.

Comment: Absolutely. Since all that's happening is an averaging of coordinates, and a factoring-out of rotational multipliers, the process naturally extends to arbitrarily-many vertices ... as well as arbitrarily-many similar figures.

Comment: It is possible to reconstruct thee initial triangle by 'answer' triangle? Like reverse algorithm. May be It will have several solutions or set of solutions?

Comment: @Nika Tvildiani , there are many different triples of triangles that will result into the same 'answer' triangle.If you need any of these, you can find $Z$ and $V$ for the 'answer' triangle, choose $2$ arbitrary equilateral triangles with parameters $z_1$, $v_1$ and $z_2$, $v_2$, and than calculate $z_3 = 3Z - z_1 - z_2$ and $v_3 = 3V - v_1 - v_2$.